# Find the Weight Values using Linear Regression Analysis in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, python-3.x

I have the equation below, which is a noise quality metric of an image:

[image]

If the `BIQS` is `1`, it means the image is clean. Else, if it is between `0` and `1`, it means the image may contain blur and noise. The smaller the value of `BIQS`, the dirty is the image. The task is to get the weights value for `w1`, `w2`,`w3` and `w4`, given the set of values `Blur_mean`, `Blur_noise`, `Noise_mean` and `Noise_ratio`, which reflects the image quality. The weights reflects how much each term (`Blur_mean, Blur_noise, Noise_mean and Noise_ratio` ) contributes to the total image quality score. For Example:

```
     Blur_mean     Blur_noise    Noise_mean       Noise_ratio
1.   0.8398212     0.8948329     0.9849308        0.89428493
2.   0.8989332     0.8989432     0.7576812        0.35546632
3.   0.4324123     0.3123232     0.2123332        0.33213233
n.   .........     .........     .........        ..........
```

I don't know the basis for identifying the appropriate values or weight for `w1`,`w2`,`w3` and `w4`. Is it possible to use linear regression analysis to find the values of `w1`, `w2`,`w3` and `w4` with almost/ close to `1` `R-square` or small standard error ? From what I observe, there are `4` independent variables here:

```
`Blur_mean`
`Blur_noise`
`Noise_mean`
`Noise_ratio`
```

Dependent Variable is `BIQS` and the unknowns are `w1`, `w2`, `w3` and `w4`. Is there any library that takes care of it in Python?

Comment: Yes, there's a python library that can do linear regression. There's some, but scikit-learn is the easiest to use in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the scikit-learn library.

From the documentation for linear regression:
"LinearRegression fits a linear model with coefficients w = (w1, ..., wp) to minimize the residual sum of squares between the observed targets in the dataset, and the targets predicted by the linear approximation."

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html